# "Operation not supported read-only collection" exception while adding controls dynamically to listbox items collection in windows phone

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to add the button controls to listbox item collection dynamically while populating the listbox. I am getting the error saying "Operation not supported read-only collection".
the following is my xaml code and later is my xaml.cs code.

```
        <ListBox x:Name="TripList" Height="465" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Background="White" Foreground="Blue">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,4">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="456">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding PUDetails}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding TripStatus}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="300">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="Conf: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding ConfNumber}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="Est Do Tm: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding DOTime}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <StackPanel x:Name="stacktest" Background="Azure" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="Svc: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding TripService}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="PU: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PURoute}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="DO: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding DORoute}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="Pax: "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PaxDetails}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                        </StackPanel>
                                 </StackPanel>
                            </Border>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>


       Grid grdtest = new Grid();
        foreach (TripsList lst in TripList.Items)
        {

            System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {

                    grdtest.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { });
                    grdtest.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { });
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    button.Margin = new Thickness(3);
                    button.Width = 80;
                    button.Height = 25;
                    button.Content = "btn1";
                    Grid.SetRow(button, 0);
                    Grid.SetColumn(button, 0);
                    grdtest.Children.Add(button);

                    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grdtest);
                    TripList.Items.Add(grdtest);

                });

        }
```

Could someone please let me know the way to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> foreach (TripsList lst in TripList.Items) 
>         { 
>
>             System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
>                 { 
>
>                     grdtest.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { }); 
>                     grdtest.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { }); 
>                     Button button = new Button(); 
>                     button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right; 
>                     button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top; 
>                     button.Margin = new Thickness(3); 
>                     button.Width = 80; 
>                     button.Height = 25; 
>                     button.Content = "btn1"; 
>                     Grid.SetRow(button, 0); 
>                     Grid.SetColumn(button, 0); 
>                     grdtest.Children.Add(button); 
>
>                     LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grdtest); 
>                     TripList.Items.Add(grdtest); 
>
>                 }); 
>
>         }
> ```

Convert this **foreach** to **for** loop. As you cannot modify the collection in foreach...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried it but then getting the same exception.

Comment: It seems you cannot add any item directly. What you can do is to add item in the collection you already binded as ItemsSource with the listbox. The listbox will automatically get updated.